# React native: how to get markers update on map?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a class of map that I get markers from DB and map them on the map screen.
I`m trying to show the new markers that changed in DB but would work only when I refresh the app.

some of the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
   
   ... 
})
// get markers from DB
    markerRef.get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      // console.log('Total users: ', querySnapshot.size);
      const markers = [];
      // if(querySnapshot)
      querySnapshot.forEach(res => {
        const {title, info, latitude, longitude, imageUri} = res.data()
        markers.push({
          latitude,
          longitude,
          title,
          info,
          imageUri,
          id: res.id
        })
      });
      this.setState({
        markers,
      })
    });
    

  }
```

on my render, I map the markers:

```
  this.state.markers.map(marker => (
          //  <<<<~~~~ I think those 2-3 lines are matter
          <MapView.Marker
            key={marker.id}
            coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
            onPress={(e)=>this.onMarkerPress(e, marker)} //
            >
            
              <MapView.Callout tooltip
                      onPress={() => this.setState({infoModal: 'true', markerUrl: marker.imageUri})}
              
              >
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}} >
                      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}> 
                        {/* {marker.imageUri &&  <Image source = {{uri:marker.imageUri}} //{{uri: marker.imageUri}}
                        style = {{ width: '90%', height: 200, justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1,}}
                        resizeMode="center"
                      /> }         */}
                      </View>
                    <Text>Lat: {marker.latitude}, Lon: {marker.longitude}</Text>
                    <Text>{marker.email}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({infoModal: 'true', markerUrl: marker.imageUri})}>
                      <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}> info </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </MapView.Callout>         
          </MapView.Marker>
        ))
      }
```

My problem is when I update an marker in DB (for example add marker/set visible - change a prop state to visible ) it wont refresh on the map, only shows after I open the app again.

is there any way to get it refreshed so after I make some change it will render on map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are fetching the markers from the db only when your component is mounting, as you are calling the data fetching method in `componentDidMount`. Therefore this will not be able to catch subsequent changes to the DB, those changes will only be reflected when you reload those components, which happens when you 'open the app again'.

What you can look into is replacing `get`  with `onSnapshot` to instantiate a listener, that will be called when the db is updated: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen